# most contact data is null when calling API but full in outlook 365 web

Tags: api, office365

i'm trying to read contact data using Office365 API.

all works great but most of the fields are null, even if the matched fields are populated in the outlook365 web console (the contacts came from google by csv import).

in the BodyPreview parameter the phones exist:

```
---------------------------- Contact Imported: Name : nnn mmm Group Membership : * My Contacts ::: android contacts Phone 1 - Type : Mobile Phone 1 - Value : 123456 Phone 2 - Type : VOICE Phone 2 - Value : 1232455"
```

if the contact is native (added in the web console), the phone are propertly shown but the address remains null

what am i doing wrong? or is it a known issue?

Comment: can you show the code of getting the contacts?

Comment: Simple API Call even in REST client:

GET https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts?$top=1000